# Conditional rendering in Polymer 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, polymer, polymer-3.x

I need to render different html based on a bool variables true or false value. For example in react I would do something like this in my return in the render function:

```
{this.state.booleanValue ? "true" : "false"}
```

Where I get two different output depending on the value of booleanValue.

I tried in Polymer 3, and first declared my bool variable:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
      myBoolValue: {
        type: Boolean
      }
    };
  }
```

I then try to use it in my template/html as

```
${this.myBoolValue ? "" : ""}
```

However, the code does not recognize the variable "this.myBoolValue" in the html template. How come? Full code of my template:

```
static get template() {
    return html`
     
     <div>
        ${this.myBoolValue ? "true" : "false"}  // error, does not recognize "this.myBoolValue". 
   </div>

    `;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your default value of `myBoolValue` is `false` you can change your properties and template like this (If you want to use [conditional templates](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if) you have to import `@polymer/polymer/lib/elements/dom-if.js`.)

```js
static get properties() {
  return {
    myBoolValue: {
      type: Boolean,
      value: false
    }
  };
}
static get template() {
  return html`
    <p>[[myBoolValue]]</p>

    // OR conditional templates:
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{myBoolValue}}">
      true
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!myBoolValue}}">
      false
    </template>
  `;
}
```

If you can't or don't want to set a default value change your code like this and use a [computed property](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/observers#computed-properties):

```js
static get properties() {
  return {
    myBoolValue: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    computedBool: {
      type: String,
      computed: "_isTrue(myBoolValue)",
      value: false
    }
  };
}

static get template() {
  return html`
    <p>[[computedBool]]</p>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{computedBool}}">
      true
    </template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{!computedBool}}">
      false
    </template>
  `;
}

_isTrue(a) {
  return a === true;
}
```